# Renaming file names using a .BAT file or any other script

Tags: batch-file, filesystems, filenames

Edit the file names of set of PDF files in a single folder in Windows 7.

I don't want to use a simple tool or something - I want to find out a simple way to do following modification to set of file names

1. Replace the "_" with blank space " "
2. Replace the 3rd character with a blank space

What is a suitable way to do this manually using a Script or Batch file etc. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a four-liner Perl script.

Comment: Please explain.. I like to learn

Comment: `set /?` will show you the way ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    set "oldname=%%~Nf"
    set "newname=!oldname:_= !"
    set "newname=!newname:~0,2! !newname:~3!"
    ren "!oldname!.pdf" "!newname!.pdf"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aacini seems very simple and clear answer. Will try this.

Comment: I created a .bat using this and run it - but did not work. The file names are as they were no change. Did I do it correctly? I have no previous experience.

Comment: Please insert an `echo ` command before the `ren ` so we may see what is the command that would be executed, so we can fix the errors.

Comment: Ops! I found the error and fixed it in my example above. Please, recopy it. :)

Comment: I tried that and It says the System cannot find the file specified.............. >>> The system cannot find the file specified.

J:\test>(
set "oldname=25_Tintin_and_the_Lake_of_Sharks"
 set "newname=_= "
 set "newname=~0,2newname:~3"
 echo on
 ren ".pdf" ".pdf"
)                                   <<<// this is the output I get with echo - my test set has 8 files and it get 8 of these similar outputs with each name respectively. But my original set has 30 files :)

Comment: Excuse me! All single % must be replaced by ! and the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` line must be inserted at beginning. The version above has been fixed... Sorry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned that you don't want to use a tool, but try "Bulk rename utility." 
It's definitely worth it. It's free and can not only replace characters, but can also handle padding.

Comment: Thanks for the tool I will check that out - just wanted to learn how to do it in scripts.

Comment: That Tool is really cool and simple - Thank you very much Chris.